# How do I reliably call the on screen keyboard in windows 10?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

I have a fullscreen C# .NET application I need to be able to call the On-Screen-Keyboard.
In Windows 7, I used: 
`Process.Start(C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe;`

With older builds of Windows 10, I was able to use `Process process = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(((Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\osk.exe"))));` (This gets the System32 location and appends the executable name.)

That worked until recently.

However now the executable is in `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-osk_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_903d5fc3c319176b\osk.exe`
So my question is, is there a reliable way to call the on-screen-keyboard that will work for the foreseeable future?

Also I'd be interested in using the touch keyboard but that's also in an odd location- `C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-tabletpc-inputpanel_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_f70fa21de0acb308\TabTip.exe`
The second windows does an update and that version updates in the folder path, a static reference to the folder becomes worthless.

Comment: Are you on an insider's build? osk is still in my System32 directory.

Answer (score 1):

If on-screen keyboard is in your environment variables (which is there by default) this code should work just fine:

`Process.Start("osk.exe");`

Comment: Odd.. Running osk.exe from Run opens the keyboard, however running the same thing using Process.Start gives me `The system cannot find the file specified`. I tried creating a ProcessStartInfo object and assigning the file name there and starting it, with the debugger I was able to confirm the path is loading from the system environment yet still shows the same error.

Comment: @CharlesIams not sure if this'll will work for you but check in your project's properties in the Build tab if Prefer 32-Bit is ticked/checked. Un-tick/Un-check it or force it to x64 platform target and see if `Process.Start("osk");` will still throw an error.